# Почему не удается найти файл, если он явно существует в PHP?

Tags: php, файлы, кодировка

В XML файле прописано название файла, который лежит в этой же папке. Далее формируется полный путь к этому файлу.

Файл называется (в файловой системе): 16.07._много букв_Д14Буквы - копия.pdf

Имя файл, который записался в переменную: 16.07._много букв_Д14БУквы — копия.pdf

Как видите различие в символе `-` и `—`. Если я применяю метод `file_exists`, то мне выдает `false`. Пробовал заменять символы и через `iconv` менять кодировку, но ничего не помогло.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне работать с таким файлом, если необходимо не изменять название файла в папке источнике (исходной папке).

Чтобы работать с ним я хочу скопировать его в отдельную директорию и дать произвольное имя, но важно сохранить его первоначальное имя, чтобы можно было провести однозначную связь. Это делается для того, чтобы циклом пробежать по таким вот файлам, открыть их и извлечь текст. Понятно, что текст не извлекается и вываливается `Exception` о том, что невозможно открыть файл. В базу я буду записывать имя исходного файла, а текст из временного нового.

Как решить такую задачу?

Благодарю.

Comment: Исходя из того что вы описали, проблема в символе и кодировке названия. Вы можете создать функцию-прокси по замене символов, либо трансформации названия, и использовать её для открытия и создания файлов. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027472/weird-dash-character-in-php)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, да потратив много времени на исследование проблемы пришел как раз к такому решению по замене всех таких символов.